# Laravel: stuck old website

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Currently I have met this issue when trying to run php artisan serve. It keep compile my old test website on XAMPP even I've shut it down already

Please refer to figure below:

```
MacBook-Pro:shop_laravel nhutnguyen$ php artisan serve
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="read_excel.php">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

Would love to receive your advises.

Comment: Clean cache of browser!

Comment: I don't think this happened on browser because this is in terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with laravel 5.1 or ahead you can try:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

And:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

If still stuck try other clean option:

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-clear-cache-from-route-view-config-and-all-cache-data-from-applicationexample.html

Comment: I try it all but the problem still the same.

Comment: Did you try to create the virtualhost by yourself? Remember to add the name to your host file. If you are on mac I would suggest you migrate to homestead.

Answer (score 0):

Not using Mac myself, but my guess is that your php compiler is still running from the xampp folder, regardless if xampp is running or not. Try to install php as stand-alone and make sure you are running it from there. In windows that's in the PATH settings. No idea how paths are created or changed in a Mac.

In other words: the php.ini settings are still the xampp settings. Hence the strange behavior.

Comment: I've removed and use PHP installed from homebrew but the old website from XAMPP still stuck right there! May be I have to try reinstall OS (_ _!)

Comment: Reinstalling seems a bit rigid. Could it be a hosts redirection? http://www.mactip.net/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Just want to update!
I've found the root cause of this issue. It didn't come from PHP, it stuck on PHP env of laravel.

**Description:**
the issue cause due to using PHP env of XAMPP and "php artisan serve" of Laravel. When running the "serve" command of artisan will grap php env and also grap stucked website, which's running on XAMPP, and then hold it on laravel env.

**Workaround:**
using "laravel new project" create a new project and then transfer you old file to the new project.

As I have been looking for clear/refresh env of laravel but found no command for this, so I've just used this workaround to passed this issue.

Any more advices please kindly to contribute, really appreciate for you advices!

```
MacBook:shop_order nhutnguyen$ php artisan serve Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```